# Problem with R downloading zipped ACS data files

Tags: r, download, zip, acs

I have been having a problem trying to download a zipped file with American Community Survey (ACS) data. The file is a zipped folder that contains zipped sub-folders within it. I want to download and unzip the file leaving the individual zipped sub-folders. The code I am using is:

```
ACS.url<-"https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/summary_file/2019/data/5_year_entire_sf/Tracts_Block_Groups_Only.zip"

dir<-getwd()

zip.file<-"CTrctACS19.zip"

zip.combine<-as.character(paste(dir,zip.file,sep="/"))

download.file(ACS.url,destfile=zip.combine,mode="wb")

unzip(zip.file)
```

After running the code I get what appears to be a correct download, but the unzip does not work. I get the following error message:

```
 In unzip(zip.file) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

The downloaded file is only about half of the size zip of the file I am trying to download (the original is 3.7G at Census website but I have about 1.8G) so I think it is not downloading the data correctly. I tried to access the downloaded file with the winzip program and it would not work either. I can download files from that website if they are smaller and don't include zipped subfolders. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `unzip` from the `zip` package, or are you using the base R version (which has some limitations for large files, according to the documentation)?

Comment: I tried downloading in R with `httr` and I got the same thing as you... a file that is only about 1.8GB that can't be opened.  I'm trying to download with chrome now but it could be that they're hosting a corrupted file.

Comment: Chrome was able to download the file successfully.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I had been using the base R version of zip. I will try the zip package. Also thanks Dean. I can manually download the file from the url but it is odd when it will not download with R. I am still working on it.